# ASP.NET MVC 5 : constructor error 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'PurchaseModule.Controllers.PurchaseController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>
> Cannot resolve parameter 'PurchaseModule.Repository.IPurchaseRepository purchaseRepo' of constructor 'Void .ctor(PurchaseModule.Repository.IPurchaseRepository, Repository.IRepository.IEmployeeCardRepository,Repository.IRepository.IDimensionRepository, Repository.IRepository.IDimensionValuesRepository, PurchaseModule.Repository.IRequestMarketRepository, PurchaseModule.Repository.IServiceMappingRepository, PurchaseModule.Repository.IFixedAssetsRepository, PurchaseModule.Repository.IPurchaseItemRepository, Repository.IRepository.IWorkflowEntriesRepository, Repository.IRepository.IWorkflowDefinitionRepository, Repository.IRepository.IWorkflowRepository, Repository.IRepository.IPositionRepository, Repository.IRepository.IEmployeeClassesRepository, Repository.IRepository.IGeneralLedgerSetupRepository, Repository.IRepository.IPayrollReportRepository, Repository.IRepository.IEmployerRepository)'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'PurchaseModule.Controllers.PurchaseController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>
> Cannot resolve parameter 'PurchaseModule.Repository.IPurchaseRepository purchaseRepo' of constructor 'Void .ctor(PurchaseModule.Repository.IPurchaseRepository, Repository.IRepository.IEmployeeCardRepository, Repository.IRepository.IDimensionRepository, Repository.IRepository.IDimensionValuesRepository, PurchaseModule.Repository.IRequestMarketRepository, PurchaseModule.Repository.IServiceMappingRepository, PurchaseModule.Repository.IFixedAssetsRepository, PurchaseModule.Repository.IPurchaseItemRepository, Repository.IRepository.IWorkflowEntriesRepository, Repository.IRepository.IWorkflowDefinitionRepository, Repository.IRepository.IWorkflowRepository, Repository.IRepository.IPositionRepository, Repository.IRepository.IEmployeeClassesRepository, Repository.IRepository.IGeneralLedgerSetupRepository, Repository.IRepository.IPayrollReportRepository, Repository.IRepository.IEmployerRepository)'.

This is my code:

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    base.Load(builder);
           
    builder.RegisterType(typeof(PurchaseAdapter)).As(typeof(IPurchaseAdapter)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType(typeof(FixedAssetsAdapter)).As(typeof(IFixedAssetsAdapter)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType(typeof(PurchaseItemAdapter)).As(typeof(IPurchaseItemAdapter)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType(typeof(ServiceMappingAdapter)).As(typeof(IServiceMappingAdapter)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType(typeof(RequestMarketAdapter)).As(typeof(IRequestMarketAdapter)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

I don't understand why I get this error. All of them are showing correctly but I can't enter the page. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot resolve parameter '`PurchaseModule.Repository.IPurchaseRepository purchaseRepo`'

None of the types registered in your `ContainerBuilder` are registered as the `IPurchaseRepository` interface.

You need to register all of the services you use in your DI container.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the abstract and concrete parts of the relevant service in your DI Container.
Because Program.cs is read once and it is referenced in runtime. If there is a DI that is not there, this runtime will also throw an error.

You have created IPurchaseRepository, connected with PurchaseRepository, passed the relevant DI in the project, but program.cs cannot find it.

It's asking you to create an empty constructor because it can't find the relevant DI, but you should be aware that if you pass an empty DI you will get an error if you create an objectReference(nullpointer).

You need;

Program.cs

```
//builder.Services.AddScoped<AbstractItem, ConcreteItem>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPurchaseRepository, PurchaseRepository>();
```